# Can a 3rd party app generate a facebook like in the background ( assuming the user is logged on via FB and agrees to like the page of course )?

Tags: android, ios, facebook

The app can redirect you to the FB page in question and get you to press the like button. Trying to understand if that can be done quicker. Tks

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible.

Facebook allowed liking certain object types in the name of the user via API until a while ago - but it has been removed since, simply because the feature was abused too much.

And Facebook pages could never be liked via API, that has always been possible via the official Like buttons only.